# chef attribute precedance not working

Tags: attributes, chef-infra, roles

I have created a role (commonrole) and applied to multiple nodes.
Now I want to override one of the attributes on 1 particular node to change to a different value.
So , created 1 more role (noderole) and applied that role after "commonrole "to this node but my node does not picks the new value (-Xmx2048m as mentioned below).

```
Sample common role-
{
  "name": "commonrole",
  "description": "Manages all nodes",
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[abc]"
      ],
  "default_attributes": {
    "catalina_opts": [
      "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"   
   ]
}

Sample noderole-
{
  "name": "noderole",
  "description": "Manages particular node",
  "run_list": [
    "role[commonrole]"
  ],
  "default_attributes": {
    "catalina_opts": [
      "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8",
      "-Xmx2048m"
   ]
 }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure no cookbook attribute use `override`  level for `catalina_opts` ? How do you confirm the value is not set ? See [attribute precedence](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-precedence) for evaluation order of the merge.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in node attributes are kind of weird. I've got a full write up on my site but basically this should result in the merged value being:

```
[
  "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8",
  "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8",
  "-Xmx2048m"
]
```

or something similar. Also remember you won't see the attribute change immediately in the `knife node show` output, only after a successful converge.